# Parsing XHTML using xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

I want to use `xml.etree.ElementTree` to parse an XHTML document in Python 3. The document contains `&nbsp;` entities, so I cannot use the default parser settings. I'd like to do something similar to:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(BASE_URL) as url:
        body = url.read()
        parser = ET.XMLParser()
        parser.parser.UseForeignDTD(True)
        parser.entity.update(entitydefs)
        etree = ET.ElementTree()
        root = etree.fromstring(body)
```

But `fromstring` is a free function in `ElementTree`. How can I achieve something similar with `ElementTree` instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I encountered same problem. The sample code in the question and the chosen answer might work before, but right now it won't work in my Python 3.3 and Python 3.4 environment.

I finally got it working. Quoted from this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35591478/how-to-parse-html-with-entities-such-as-nbsp-using-builtin-library-elementtree).

Inspired by [this post](http://forums.devshed.com/xml-programming-19/xml-parsing-error-undefined-entity-564981.html), we can just prepend some XML definition to the incoming raw HTML content, and then ElementTree would work out of box.

This works for both Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, 3.4.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

html = '''<html>
    <div>Some reasonably well-formed HTML content.</div>
    <form action="login">
    <input name="foo" value="bar"/>
    <input name="username"/><input name="password"/>

    <div>It is not unusual to see &nbsp; in an HTML page.</div>

    </form></html>'''

magic = '''<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" [
            <!ENTITY nbsp ' '>
            ]>'''  # You can define more entities here, if needed

et = ET.fromstring(magic + html)
```

Answer (score 1):

Feed the parser:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(BASE_URL) as url:
    body = url.read()
    parser = ET.XMLParser()
    parser.parser.UseForeignDTD(True)
    parser.entity.update(entitydefs)
    parser.feed(body)
    root = parser.close()   # this returns you the tree
```

Comment: Original poster asked for Python 3 solution, but `parser.parser.UseForeignDTD(True)` doesn't work in Python 3. How come this answer was chosen as the correct answer?