# Parsing XHTML including standard entities using ElementTree

Tags: python, parsing, xhtml, elementtree

Consider the following snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head><title>&copy;</title></head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

It is deemed valid XHTML 1.0 Transitional per W3C's validator (https://validator.w3.org/).  However, Python (3.7)'s ElementTree chokes on it with

```
$ python -c 'from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET; ET.parse("foo.html")'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1197, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 598, in parse
    self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: undefined entity &copy;: line 4, column 15
```

Note that `&copy;` is indeed an entity defined (ultimately) in `xhtml-lat1.ent`.

Is there a way to parse such documents using ElementTree?  [An answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35591479/378080) suggested manually prepending the appropritate XML definitions to the HTML content (e.g. `<!ENTITY nbsp ' '>`) but that's not really a general solution (unless one prepends a header with all definitions to any document, but it seems like there should be something simpler?).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stupid question probably, but is "foo.html" the name of the file you're parsing? That would be HTML, not XHTML; doesn't that throw the parser off?

Comment: That doesn't matter (rename it as xhtml if you want, error stays).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider about `lxml`?

```
from lxml import html


root = html.fromstring("""
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head><title>&copy;</title></head>
  <body></body>
</html>
""".strip())
print(root.head.getchildren()[0].text)
# '©'
```

`&copy;` is not valid in xml. `xml` package really parse xml but not html. Actually built-in html parser do **can** parse this content:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser


parser = HTMLParser()
parser.feed("""
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head><title>&copy;</title></head>
  <body></body>
</html>
""".strip())
# no error
```

But its api is really difficult to use lol. `lxml` provides an equivalent api.

Comment: It would seem like there should be a builtin solution, but sure, lxml is good enough.

Comment: @antony Well, if you can accept using `html.parser.HTMLParser`, you do can use a builtin solution.

Answer (score 0):

In python3.4+ you can use `html.unescape` to convert html5 entity references into the respective unicode characters. After that, any xml parser works.

```
from html import escape, unescape
textXML = re.sub("\\&\\w+\\;", lambda x: escape(unescape(x.group(0))), text)
```